# How to delete a line from a data set if the value in a specific column is known?

Tags: python, pandas

I have in my data set column activity which contains numbers from 1 to 7, but there is a line with a zero in this column

using inst  `data['activity'].value_counts()` I got

```
7    83748
1    33676
4    26860
3    11179
5     3191
6     2917
2      928
0        1
Name: activity, dtype: int64
```

so I want to delete the entire line to have result like:

```
7    83748
1    33676
4    26860
3    11179
5     3191
6     2917
2      928
Name: activity, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any more information than what you have provided, I think you can use the DataFrame.drop method as follows:

```
df.drop(axis=0, index=0, inplace=True)¶
```

Comment: this generate KeyError: '[0] not found in axis'

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```py
data = data.drop(data[data.activity == 0].index)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `data = data.loc[data['activity'] != 0]`